# Disable directory listing on apache; but access to individual files should be allowed

Tags: apache, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I do not want to use .htaccess. How should I change my Directory attributes?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName abc.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/share/uploads
   <Directory " /usr/share/uploads">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I really couldnt find a direct answer on internet ; even on apache documentation. Finally, could find the solution through few iterations; we need to use Options and the value should NOT contain Indexes.

```
<Directory "/usr/share/uploads">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
         Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
```

Comment: The relevant documentation is the [Options](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) section of the core feature page, which describes the affects of the "Indexes" option. You can also disable/enable individual options by prefixing them with -/+, without affecting any other options previously set: `Options -Indexes`.

Answer (score 56):

If you are using Debian/Ubuntu, just go to terminal and type

```
sudo a2dismod autoindex
sudo service apache2 restart
```

If you are using Centos/Fedora, just do:

```
mv /etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.bkp
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

And similarly in other OS or distros...

This should disable the apache module that makes those fancy (normally useless and a security problem) directory listings. Also, as a bonus, you earn a bit of performance :-)

Comment: Can't get easier then this solution

Comment: or in wamp (on windows) in httpd.conf put "#" in front of  

    Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf  and  
    LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so

Comment: I've edited every single configuration file across my entire server and couldn't get those directory index pages to stop. This did the trick. You should have the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

The @Deepak solution did not worked for me. This one did:

In the main apace configuration ***/etc/apache2/httpd.conf*** just add:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And it will work for all of you domains and subdomains. Without .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

All done above, but the directory info is still coming up?
If you use index.php, rather than index.html, Check the following:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

on my AWS ec2, i did this and it worked for me.

First open /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file.

modify/add

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to put an empty index.html (or whatever you apache is configured to deliver by default) inside that directory.
This is not a real solution but a very simple workaround. The user browsing that directory would just see a blank white page.

Further you could use a script (like index.php) wich emulates the directory-listing and only shows some special files.

Comment: This uploads directory is not a webapp which can have index.jsp and anyway that is not a good solution either.