# When I go to www.mywebsite.com/static/ I can view a directory/index of all my django static files. Is this safe and how can I block it?

Tags: django, static

Like the question says, my django static files are visible at website.com/static
How can I hide it from the public like other django websites, and should I be worried?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/vhosts/abcd/static"  # '' is the default

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://example.com/static/", "http://static.example.com/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_IN_VIEW_URL = 'http://mywebsite.com/static/'
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136913/disable-directory-listing-on-apache-but-access-to-individual-files-should-be-al

Comment: can you post your related STATIC (ROOT, URL, DIRS) variables from your settings?

Comment: sure included it in the EDIt